# How to get several counts of different data in a column depending on a combination of data from different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

Say I have the following data in a table called tbl_decisions:

| Decision1 | Decision2 | Open | Close | Current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | Sales | Marketing | Marketing |
| B | C | HR | IT | HR |
| D | F | Marketing | Marketing | HR |
| D | F | Marketing | Marketing | Marketing |
| E | B | IT | IT | IT |
| E | B | IT | HR | IT |

This is not an exhaustive list, and I am dealing with a very large dataset so we can assume that there will be all manner of combinations of decisions.

A bit of information so you can understand the data:
A case is opened and two decisions are made on it.
'Open' refers to where the case resided when the case was opened.
'Close' refers to where the case resided when it was closed.
'Current' refers to where the case resides currently at this point in time.

For each combination of decision (A&B, A&B, A&C...F&A, F&B, F&C and so on), I am trying to get a count of how many cases were in each department.

I wish to split the results into 3 columns for each department (I have 5 departments).

So using the example data above and taking only the 'Marketing' and 'IT' departments, I should get the following results:

| Decision1 | Decision2 | Marketing_Open | Marketing_Close | Marketing_ Cur | IT_Open | IT Close | IT_Cut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | C | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| C | F | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| D | F | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| E | B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| F | E | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I have done the following:

```
SELECT
    DECISION1,
    DECISION2,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TBL_DECISIONS D2 WHERE D2.OPEN = 'Marketing' AND D2.DECISION1 = D1.DECISION1 AND D2.DECISION2 = D1.DECISION2) AS 'Marketing Open',
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TBL_DECISIONS D2 WHERE D2.CLOSE = 'Marketing' AND D2.DECISION1 = D1.DECISION1 AND D2.DECISION2 = D1.DECISION2) AS 'Marketing Close',
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TBL_DECISIONS D2 WHERE D2.OPEN = 'Marketing' AND D2.DECISION1 = D1.DECISION1 AND D2.DECISION2 = D1.DECISION2) AS 'Marketing Close',
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TBL_DECISIONS D2 WHERE D2.OPEN = 'IT' AND D2.DECISION1 = D1.DECISION1 AND D2.DECISION2 = D1.DECISION2) AS 'IT Open',
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TBL_DECISIONS D2 WHERE D2.CLOSE = 'IT' AND D2.DECISION1 = D1.DECISION1 AND D2.DECISION2 = D1.DECISION2) AS 'IT Close',
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TBL_DECISIONS D2 WHERE D2.OPEN = 'IT' AND D2.DECISION1 = D1.DECISION1 AND D2.DECISION2 = D1.DECISION2) AS 'IT Close'
FROM
    TBL_DECISIONS D1
GROUP BY
    DECISION1,
    DECISION2
```

I know this isn't the best way to do it (at all!) and it's so much unnecessary processing power, but my head at this point in time has gone down the road and I can't think of how else to do it. I just can't seem to put my finger on it. I'm not asking for the code really, I'm just wondering how you would go about it? I know there's a far easier way of doing it that doesn't take an age to run.

Comment: You can do a case statement in your select like SUM(Case when D2.Open = 'Marketing' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )  This will give you a 1 when it matches your criteria and then you sum them up.  Then you can have multiple case statements for each amount you want to get counts for.

Comment: Here's how to create a proper table in Markdown: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: [dbfiddle of your input data](https://dbfiddle.uk/YrpI85OT). I changed some column names so they're not reserved keywords.

Comment: @Brad Thank you - that works perfectly. I knew it would be something simple! Thanks ever so much.

Comment: @rgettman, don't promote those horrible, screen wasting, hard to read MD tables. Simple tables are much more effective.

Comment: The technique in Brad's answer is commonly called *conditional aggregation*. An equivalent alternative that is sometimes used is `COUNT(CASE WHEN D2.Open = 'Marketing' AND ... THEN 1 END) AS 'Marketing Open'`. The non-null `THEN 1` is counted, while the implicit `ELSE NULL` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was provided by Brad in the comments:

You can do a case statement in your select like SUM(Case when D2.Open = 'Marketing' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) This will give you a 1 when it matches your criteria and then you sum them up. Then you can have multiple case statements for each amount you want to get counts for. –
Brad
Feb 9 at 17:55